# To fetch hash tags from a string in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, hash, user-defined-functions

Friends,
I want to fetch hashtags from a field.

```
select PREG_RLIKE("/[[:<:]]abcd[[:>:]]/","okok got it #abcd"); 
//output 1
```

BUT

```
select PREG_RLIKE("/[[:<:]]#abcd[[:>:]]/","okok got it #abcd"); 
//output 0
```

not getting why `#` is not considering
Please help

Comment: Because of the word boundary. It will find a match in `"okok got it#abcd"`. Also, if you are using PCRE, why use MySQL like word boundaries? Use `\b`. Or, as in this case, use `(?<!\w)#abcd(?!\w)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern matches:

- `[[:<:]]` - a leading word boundary
- `#abcd`  - a literal string
- `[[:>:]]` - a trailing word boundary.

Since a leading word boundary is a location between a non-word and a word char (or start of a string and a word char), you can't expect it to be matched between a space (non-word char) and a hash symbol (`#`).

Since you are using a PCRE based [UDF function](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg), use lookarounds:

```
select PREG_RLIKE("/(?<!\\w)#abcd(?!\\w)/","okok got it #abcd");
```

The `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind acts like a leading word boundary failing the match if the search term is preceded with a word char, and `(?!\w)` negative lookahead fails the match if the search term is followed with a word char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z7SrqY/1).